# grade sync failed android studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Recently installed android studio bundle 2.3.3 ...When I create a new project the following error shows:

`gradle project refresh failed error:could not create parent directory for lock file C:\ProgramFiles\Android\AndroidStudio\gradle\gradle-3.2\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all\55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9\gradle-3.3-all.zip.lck`

Comment: Try File -> Invalidate Cashes/ Restart : Invalidate and restart. Also verify you have all you SDK and AS updated

Comment: Tried invalidate and restart but not working still...how to verify SDK and AS are uptodate

Comment: Can you share your project's `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @user8408181 Go to Tools -> Android -> SDK manager